# Why do I get "undefined method 'fetch' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm parsing JSON data to save to my db.

The JSON data is like this:

```
{"id"=>889066,
  "email"=>"new.user@email.com",
  "created_at"=>"2014-10-24T18:46:13Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2014-10-24T18:46:13Z",
  "status"=>"Registered",
  "custom_status"=>nil,
  "first_name"=>New,
  "last_name"=>User,
  "latest_visitor"=>
   {"id"=>16998604, "tracking_code"=>"cab237f6-50ec-4424-9ea9-b0110070a6cb"},
  "url"=>{"id"=>2422287, "url"=>"http://www.website.com/"},
  "referrer"=>{"id"=>4234808, "url"=>"https://www.google.ba/"},
  "affiliate"=>nil,
  "campaign"=>nil,
  "search_term"=>
   {"id"=>344901, "term"=>"puppies", "search_engine"=>"google"},
  "tracking_code"=>"cab237f6-50ec-4424-9ea9-b0110070a6cb"}]
```

For example I want to get the search engine value, so I do:

```
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
json.each do |item|
  Model.create(
    search_engine: item.fetch("search_term").fetch("search_engine")
    )
end
```

This returns the error:

```
in 'block in <top (required)>': undefined method 'fetch' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

EDIT: Here is the output of `puts item.keys`:

```
id
email
created_at
updated_at
status
custom_status
first_name
last_name
latest_visitor
url
referrer
affiliate
campaign
search_term
tracking_code
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is because you are calling fetch on a nil object. Either because your "item" is nil or because whatever is returned by the first fetch returns nil. Break this into two lines and uses some prints to find out which one is nil.

Comment: The second fetch raises the error. I can't figure out why it would be nil when it has a value.

Comment: That means out "item" is not what you think it is. Try `puts item.keys` and make sure "search_term" is present.

Comment: based on what you have presented there is nothing wrong which means what you have presented must be incorrect.

Comment: @roychri I've added the output of `puts item.keys`

Comment: @engineersmnky I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: @NeyLive you seem to be iterating over a list of items. Your sample JSON does not reflect that. Also, your sample JSON has "New" and "User" as class names and not strings. Maybe one of the items your iterating over does not have the search_term key. Can you update your code to count the item numbers and rescue NoMethodError and display which json item number is causing the error?

Comment: @roychri I'm a little embarrassed to say I haven't quite got the hang of rescuing in begin-end blocks yet. You are correct, I am iterating over an array of JSON objects from an API, well at least I'm attempting to.

Comment: Sorry, it wont format properly. One sec...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/roychri/043415c96f2f470c4466afd1032e7cd7

Comment: @roychri Thanks for that. I see that `"search_term"=>nil` for all the items that raise the error. Is there anything I can do to get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is detect when the search_term is nil and do something about it.

If you want to discard it, that's easy

```
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
json.each do |item|
  search_term = item.fetch("search_term")
  next if search_term.nil?
  Model.create(
    search_engine: search_term.fetch("search_engine")
    )
end
```

If you want to provide some default search_engine value when there are no search_term:

```
DEFAULT_SEARCH_ENGINE = "N/A"
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
json.each do |item|
  search_term = item.fetch("search_term")
  if search_term.nil?
    search_engine = DEFAULT_SEARCH_ENGINE
  else
    search_engine = search_term.fetch("search_engine")
  end
  Model.create(
    search_engine: search_engine
    )
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work through this with me! You've been a huge help and I learned a lot from you today.